# CSS: Image overlapping drop down menu <DIV>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this jQuery Autocomplete which fetches the results from a database. But for some reason, the results get;s hidden behind this image after milliseconds of loading of the results. How should I stop this? So that the results do not get hidden behind the image?
Any suggestions are helpful.

Image
[image]

My CSS Code

```
#suggestions {
    display: none;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -10px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 40%;
}

#searchresults {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #919191;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 64%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 14px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 9px;
}

#searchresults a {
    display: block;
    /*background-color: #e4e4e4;*/
    background-image: url(../images/hdr-bg.png);
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 56px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#searchresults a:hover {
    background-color: #b7b7b7;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#searchresults a img {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

#searchresults a span.searchheading {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
}

#searchresults a:hover span.searchheading {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#searchresults a span {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#searchresults a:hover span {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#searchresults span.category {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#searchresults span.seperator {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-image: url(../images/shortcuts_arrow.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}

#searchresults span.seperator a {
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    height: auto;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Set the `z index` higher.

Comment: Experiment with setting the z-index of the image to negative, or 999 for the autocomplete.

Comment: can you create a demo of code using jsfiddle.net and share? That will be more helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CSS `z-index` property to specify the stack order of the results div. For example:

```
z-index: 99;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try position attribute along with z-index. Need HTML to analyze further.